# Logout using a command inside a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to write a bash script that does the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello World"

while [ true ] 
do
echo "Do you want to logout? [Yes]/[No]"
read x
if [ "$x" = "Yes" ]
  # here should come the logout command
else
  exit;
fi
done
```

I've come to exec, however i don't want the option with `exec ./myScript.sh`, but rather as shown above

Thanks in advance

Comment: Logout from what? A graphical session (e.g. gnome, KDE, ...), a tty terminal session, an ssh connection, ...?

Comment: From the subshell that runs this script. Impossible this way.

Comment: @Socowi from the system so that the user comes to the log in screen

Comment: An answer could depend on your environment (gnome vs. KDE vs. unity, ... and X vs. Wayland and lightdm vs. GDM, ...). Please add this information to your question by [edit]ing.

Comment: I'm a little bit stumped i must say. I'm  begineer with bash. I'm working on ubuntu from the command line

Comment: If you don't know any of these terms then you likely didn't install any of this yourself. Just specify your exact version of Ubuntu (version number and flavour, e.g. Kubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) and we will figure it out for you.

Comment: @Socowi. lets say i'm looking for a command that does the same as if i run `exec ./myScript.sh`

Comment: But `exec ./myScript.sh` is **completly** different from returning to the login screen. I'm really confused. And if you basically want `exec ./myScript.sh`, then why not use it?

Comment: @Socowi `Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic `

Comment: @Socowi. I would use it if i knew how but inside the script :'). I mean i want to let the user decides whether he/she want to logout or not (inside the if statement!)

Comment: But don't you already let the user decide? Why else would there be an `if [ $x = yes ]` in your code? If you want to execute `exec ./myScript.sh` just write it inside the `if`.

Comment: @Socowi if the user types `Yes` , a logout must occurs!. and all i'm asking how does this command look like?

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/180660/1121748) answer your question?

Comment: Certainly not `exec ./myScript.sh` (unless that script contains code that logs you out. But then you wouldn't have to ask here, right?). Maybe this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/180628/how-can-i-logout-from-the-gui-using-cli